# writing content in an Excel sheet

Tags: java, android, jxl

I am developing an application in android and I have a requirement to read and write from an excel file stored in sdcard.I am using jxl library for this purpose. But I am getting some errors with file operation.

```
ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/hai/dynamic.xls";
setOutputFile(ext);
try {
    write();
} catch (WriteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputfile = inputFile;
    }

public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
        File file = new File(inputfile);
        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
        workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        createLabel(excelSheet);
        createContent(excelSheet);

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }
```

Then I am getting this following error in logcat

```
01-09 12:43:12.824: W/System.err(12321):     java.io.FileNotFoundException:/mnt/sdcard/hai/dynamic.xls (Permission denied)
01-09 12:43:12.884: W/System.err(12321):    at  org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
01-09 12:43:12.884: W/System.err(12321):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:66)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at jxl.Workbook.createWorkbook(Workbook.java:301)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at com.fis.excel.WriteAcivity.write(WriteAcivity.java:59)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at com.fis.excel.WriteAcivity.onCreate(WriteAcivity.java:40)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-09 12:43:12.904: W/System.err(12321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-09 12:43:12.916: W/System.err(12321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-09 12:43:12.916: W/System.err(12321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-09 12:43:12.924: W/System.err(12321):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-09 12:43:12.924: W/System.err(12321):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 12:43:12.924: W/System.err(12321):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 12:43:12.924: W/System.err(12321):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-09 12:43:12.924: W/System.err(12321):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-09 12:43:12.944: W/System.err(12321):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-09 12:43:12.944: W/System.err(12321):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-09 12:43:12.944: W/System.err(12321):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-09 12:43:12.944: W/System.err(12321):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check your path ,And print this ...System.out.println("File is :: " +ext);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//add use permission in your manifest

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Allows an application to write to external storage


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```